# MicrosoftGraph - Batch request - how to send first API response to second one?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a problem with a simple batch request...

```html
  const batchRequestContent = {
    requests: [
      {
        id: "1",
        $referenceId: "getUsersList",
        name: "getUsers",
        url: "/userse",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          ConsistencyLevel: "eventual",
        },
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        dependsOn: ["1"],
        url: "communications/getPresencesByUserId",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: { ids: [] }, //those ID's are returned by first API (getUsers)
      },
    ],
  };
  const response = await _MSGraphClient.api("$batch").post(batchRequestContent);
```

How can i append getUsers response to second API body?
Thanks!

i tried different methods, like converting from JSON to JS
i tried with [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_record_manipulation.htm) with @ reference, and nothing worked...

Comment: That link your referencing is for SalesForce and referenceId isn't in the OData spec http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/odata-json-format-v4.01.html#sec_BatchRequestsandResponses. Even if Microsoft did implement everything in the spec (which I don't think they do) it would only support single entities

Comment: Just checking did the above information helped you and is your issue resooved?